# C# Open form using generics?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have a main form with a menu that contains lots of items which in turn open different forms. Currently I do the following to open a particular form:

```
        if (canShowCustomerForm)
            new CustomerForm().ShowDialog(this);
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough rights to view this form.");
        }
```

Is there a way to move this code in a class and then passing the form type and boolean parameter instead of repeating the code for each and every menu item?

Comment: Never do it this way, slapping the user with a message box to tell him that he did something stupid is just ugly.  This is your problem, not the user's, you forgot to disable the menu item.  And of course trivially solves your problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static DisplayResult ShowForm<T>(IWin32Window owner, bool canShowForm)
        where T : Form, new()
    {
        if (canShowForm)
        {
            using (T form = new T())
            {
                return form.ShowDialog(owner);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough rights to view this form.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to dispose of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing the same logic over and over again you can extract it into a function like below:

```
void ShowFormIfAllowed<TForm>(bool allowed) where TForm : Form, new() {
      if (allowed) {
          using (var form = new TForm()) {
               form.ShowDialog(this);
          }
      }
      else {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough rights to view this form.");
      }
 }
```

Then in your menu handling you can call it like:

```
ShowFormIfAllowed<CustomerForm>(canShowCustomerForm);
```